# What is the correct position for saving a list as a result of two nested for loops in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, nested-loops

The iteration must start with **p** =1, then, the second for loop must sum all the values for the range of **r**. After the second loop finish, I want to save the result in the first element of the list (**ap**) . Then, **p**= 2 and the process is repetead, and the new value of a, must be save it in the second element of the list ap... and so on and so forth

I am trying this with a dataframe from which I already know what the result would be, that is why I know that my code is doing another different thing . I guess the position of the ap list is not in the correct place?
Do I have to try with Series in pandas, or arrays with Numpy?

Thank you for your help

```
 m=12
    n=6
    ap=[]
    
    for p in range(1,n):
        for r in range(-n,n):
            a = a + (1/n)*((data3.loc[r].iat[1])*(np.cos((2*(np.pi)*p*r)/m)))
            ap  += [a]    
            #?
            #?
```

Comment: You probably need to initialize `a` to `0` at the beginning of the `p` loop, otherwise you're adding to the total from the previous `p` value.

Comment: The normal way to add to a list is `ap.append(a)`

Comment: The list append should also happen outside the `for r in ...` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can reorganize your code using functions and generator expressions to be a little neater. Also your formula seems to have a bunch of unnecessary parentheses.

```py
m = 12
n = 6
ap = []

def calculate(p, r):
    return (1/n) * data3.loc[r].iat[1] * np.cos(2*np.pi * p * r) / m

for p in range(1, n):
    a = sum(calculate(p, r) for r in range(-n, n))
    ap.append(a)
```

This will create a list `ap` of length `n-1`

Comment: Thank you @Adam Smith!  It works perfectly!  I just changed the position of the "m"   return (1/n) * data3.loc[r].iat[1] * np.cos( 2 * np.pi * p * r/ m)  , because "m" is part of the argument of cosine.